# why rollback doesn't give back the original value?

Tags: hibernate

I have the following **simplified** Hibernate testing code to see how **rollback** works.

```
Session session = MySessionFactory.getSession();
Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
try
{
    //1. get a persistent User
    User user = (User) session.get(User.class, user3Id);
    System.out.println("1. original: user.username=" + user.getUsername());

    //2. update it
    String newUserName = userName3 + "Updated";
    user.setUsername(newUserName);
    session.saveOrUpdate(user);
    session.flush();
    System.out.println("2. updated: user.username=" + user.getUsername());

    //3. rollback
    tx.rollback();
    System.out.println("3. rollback: user.username=" + user.getUsername());

    //4. session close
    session.close();
    System.out.println("4. session close: user.username=" + user.getUsername());
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    tx.rollback();

    throw e;
}
finally
{
    session.close();
}
```

What it does is this:

1. get a persistent object from database;
2. update its name field;
3. rollback the transaction;

For each step, I print out the value of the **username** field. I expect the username **after the rollback** should the username get from **step 1**. But the print out **is not**: all the  printout of 2,3,4 are the same, the updated name string.

So the rollback is just rollback **database** but not the **persistent objects**?

What **extra work** I have to do to get the persistent object being rollback to its original state, the step 1 state?

Comment: Yes, it only rolls back the database. I would not try to continue working with this Hibernate session and its associated objects. Cannot you just get the entities afresh?

Comment: This is a volunteering rollback. If it is due to exception, it makes sense to have a new session. So we treat rollback the same as the hibernate access exception?

Comment: For me, transactional work means, either complete it or throw all of it away. Regardless of having to rollback because of an exception, or because of "business logic". Simple principle, keeps things from getting messed up.

Comment: This behavior confused me. I modified the persistent object, and then update it with database, I expect the database and the persistent object are the same now. But after the rollback, the persistent object are not the same as the database. Why the Hibernate cannot do the synchronization here for the rollback case? I understand the exception case which may be impossible to synchronize them then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flushing the session forces Hibernate to synchronize the in-memory state of the Session with the database. You can say an other way to commit the changes without running commit() method.

> What extra work I have to do to get the persistent object being rollback to its original state, the step 1 state?

Remove session.flush() before the rollback.

Comment: I removed that session.flush(), the printout result is exactly the same. ??

Comment: after rollback try  `session.refresh(user)` to refresh its state from db. than you will see the changes.